# Get occurrence of string, containing single or double citation marks using grep

Tags: bash, grep, translation

I'm checking usage of translation strings in language.ini. Developers in the project use `''`, but might use even `""` because PHP allows both (even though there's quite a difference between those).

Also there's usage of variables;

```
$thisText = !true ? 'Xyz' : 'Abcd';
$this->translate($thisText);
```

The problem is to correctly wrap the expression containing even single or double quotes - something like `["']translation string["']`

Is there way to check files with grep for occurrence of something like that in Bash Command line?

---

Example

```
file a.php, b.php, c.phtml, d.js

a.php:
$transString = rand(0,42) == 42 ? 'Search results' : 'Nothing found';
$this->translate($transString);

b.php:
//translate 'Location'
return $this->translate("Location");

c.phtml:
<?= $this->translate('Location'); ?>

d:
trans.translate('current_location');
```

Want to match `translate("Location")` or `translate('Location');` and `'Location'`

If I look for eg. `"42"` it should look for `"42"` `'42'`

Comment: Yes, probably. Include examples in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to escape `"[\"']"`

```
egrep -r --include=\*.{php,phtml,js} --exclude-dir={languages} "[\"']${term}[\"']" ./
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `grep -e` to grep for multiple pattern

```
echo -e "translate('location')\ntranslate(\"location\")" | grep -F -e "translate('location')" -e 'translate("location")'
```